# ClassNotFoundException on some external libraries only in release build?

Tags: android, android-studio, classnotfoundexception

In Android studio my app crashes in the release build with the exception int he title being thrown formultiple libraries that are meant to be included.

As far as I can see release and debug build settings have nothing different but only debug loads successfully..

Comment: Are you using proguard for release build

Comment: settings are the same for debug and release, I haven't specified touse proguard but there is a proguardFiles defined in the build types under release and debug..